# Dismiss keyboard in an iOS Notification Content Extension

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm presenting custom action buttons in my iOS 11 notification window via a Notification Content Extension target.  One of them is a 'comment' button.  If I press it the keyboard shows up properly, but I am not able to figure out how to have the keyboard go away and get back to the other buttons on the notification.  There's not really anything I can see to call `resignFirstResponder` on.  Am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Is this using a UNTextInputNotificationAction?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this.

**Without A Content Extension**
The first does not even require a notification content extension! The `UNTextInputNotificationAction` does all of the work for you. When initializing the action you specify parameters for the text field that will be presented when the action is triggered. That action is attached to your notification category during registration (i.e. inside `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`):

```
userNotificationCenter.getNotificationCategories { (categories) in
    var categories: Set<UNNotificationCategory> = categories
    let inputAction: UNTextInputNotificationAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "org.quellish.textInput", title: "Comment", options: [], textInputButtonTitle: "Done", textInputPlaceholder: "This is awesome!")
    let category: UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: notificationCategory, actions: [inputAction], intentIdentifiers: [], hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: "Placeholder", options: [])

    categories.insert(category)
    userNotificationCenter.setNotificationCategories(categories)
}
```

This will produce an experience like this:

[image: UNTextInputNotificationAction]

Note that by default, the "Done" button dismisses the keyboard and notification.

With more than one action you get this:

[image: Multiple actions]

There is no going back to the action buttons that were presented with the notification - notifications can't do that. To see those actions choices again would require showing another notification.

**With a Content Extension**
First, the above section works with a content extension as well. When the user finishes entering text and hits the "textInputButton" the `didReceive(_:completionHandler:)` method of the content extension is called. This is an opportunity to use the input or dismiss the extension. The WWDC 2016 session [Advanced Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/) describes this same use case and details ways it can be customized further.

This may not meet your needs. You may want to have a customized text entry user interface, etc. In that case it is up to your extension to handle showing and hiding the keyboard. The responder that handles text input - a UITextField, for example - should become first responder when the notification is received. Doing so will show the keyboard. Resigning first responder will hide it. This can be done inside a `UITextField` delegate method.

For example, this:

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.label?.text = notification.request.content.body
    self.textField?.delegate = self
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.textField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    return
}


// UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.textField?.resignFirstResponder()
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Produces a result like this:

[image: content extension]

Keep in mind that on iOS 10 and 11 any taps on the notification itself - like on your text field - may result in it being dismissed! For this and many other reasons going this route is probably not desirable.

Comment: So I just need to define an `inputAccessoryView` that returns a `UITextField`?  Seems easy enough.  I'll work on that tomorrow.  Thanks much.  As soon I as get it working I'll come back and mark this the answer.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you generate the text field?  I'm struggling to get that part right for some reason.

Comment: How do I add a button inside this to dismiss the notification adn remove it after I enter text and say submit